# PHP add +1 in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have while loop and in that there's forum posts.I want to show number of posts (1,2..).

Let me show you what i think

```
while($some = mysql_fetch_array($forum_posts)){
echo 'Number of post is $num++';
}
```

and show like

------ Thread -------

------ Posts  -------

```
Text of post            1.
Text of post            2.
Text of post            3.
```

Thanks.Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$num must be initialized!

```
$num = 1;
while($some = mysql_fetch_array($forum_posts)){
echo 'Number of post is '.($num++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$num = 0;

while($some = mysql_fetch_array($forum_posts)){
    echo 'Number of post is '.++$num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$num = 1;
while($some = mysql_fetch_array($forum_posts)){
   echo 'Number of post is ' . ($num++) . '.';
}
```

Variables have to be outside string.